# How to integrate payment gateway in applications created using javascript frameworks like ExtJs?

Tags: extjs, payment-gateway, javascript, javascript-framework

Our application is a one-page application created using ExtJs. **For any user action, the browser tab is never reloaded and all the actions are performed using ajax. A user can open/close multiple ExtJs windows/panels within the same browser tab, and this way everything remains confined to the same browser tab.**

Now, we need to integrate payment gateway in the application, which involves redirecting the user to the bank website and having her brought back to our application.

**The issue is that when browser redirects the user, then all the application javascript code along with panels and windows get destroyed, and when the user comes back to the application then she finds it to be different from one she left.**

As a solution to this, we were thinking of using following two appraoches:

***Option 1. Maintaining the state of application*** - When user leaves for the bank's website then somehow we maintain the state of application - like which windows are opened carrying what data, which variables have which values etc.. and when user returns back, we generate the same application state for her.

***Option 2. Have a browser pop-up window for payment gateway*** - We intend to provide a button which will open a small pop-up window carrying the transaction details, and in this pop-up window the entire payment gateway process will take place taking care of redirection and everything.

Option 1 is proving to be very cumbersome and complicated as maintaining the exact state is not getting feasible.

For Option 2, we are not sure if this is safe and possible?

Has anyone implemented such an approach earlier. Otherwise, what are the other options which we can go for?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the problem and I implemented it using websocket/polling in the main application while a new window pops up for the payment.

After the payment is successful the main application will be notified.

That way each payment runs in it own sandbox totally unbound from the main application which makes maintenance quite easy. Note that our backend create a new session for each payment using the existing one.

I think it is not uncommon to open new windows for payment that's why I decided to go this.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your approach of pop-up window. Interesting to find that you are using websocket/polling for the notifying the parent window. We are actually planning to invoke a function at parent window on unload/close of the child window for this notification if going for pop-up approach. Have you also tried that and found any issues with it which made you choose websocket option?

Comment: @netemp The goal was to keep them totally separated from the beginning. That is why I focused on that approach. It was more a design thing then any known issue.

Comment: Thanks for the point mentioned. Could you also share that did you face any issue with pop-blocker? Did you have complaints that pop-ups are generally blocked by the browsers and thus should be avoided?

Comment: @netemp No, I don't. At least my customer never get back to me with that. So I can't say it for sure. But I really doubt that this would be a serious problem if the popup is opened by clicked link. The pop url also refers to the same domain cause first I contact the application server before this redirects to the payment provider. I don't know it for sure but I think this may make a difference for most pop up blockers to rate it as no advertisement. But this is just I guess, I never needed to look closer.

Comment: Thanks @sra. We too created a small prototype and found that pop-ups are not being blocked given they are opening with a button click. Thanks for the time so far and inputs.

Comment: In this model, what exactly is the SPA polling via the socket? Is it polling its 'own' API server, which is somehow receiving updates about payment state through a separate channel to the payment processor? Does it have a separate connection to the bank/payment gateway, which allows it to receive updates, but just not do full processing? What's the data flow back from the processor to the SPA?